# OpenCV create tiff with altimetry info

Tags: c++, opencv, tiff

Is it possible to create a tiff image with some other band of, for instance,  floats, using OpenCV or some similar lib?

I want to store the RGB data along with a parallel channel for some float value for every pixel. Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to create non-standard TIFF images, I would recommend using libTiff or GDAL.  OpenCV is good for generating the data, but it is designed to write normal images.  Special band and raster formats are more GDAL's forte.

Comment: @msmith81886 sure I've read something about that. But is it not possible to add an extra band via OpenCV?